# Python multiprocess script doesnt exit on ctrl+c

Tags: python, multiprocess

I have a script, that runs various multiprocesses. These multiprocesses does not open child processes themself!

I now try to close the script with the Keyboardinterrupt. I see that all processes are terminated and joined. But the main process with not die. Why is that? I dont understand it...

Here is the code for the main process:

```
from position_pipeline import Pipeline as PositionPipeline
from relay_control import RelayControl
from server import run_webserver
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Queue
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys



def run_pipeline(pipeline, position_queue):
    pipeline.load_calibration()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("sample-video.mp4")

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    pipeline.load_image(frame) 
    pipeline.preprocess_image()

    pipeline.detect_circles()
    pipeline.calibrate()
    pipeline.store_calibration()

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if np.sum(frame) == None:
            break
        pipeline.load_image(frame)
        pipeline.preprocess_image()

        #pipeline.calibrate() maybe try to recalibrate very 100 iterations brcause of af distortion

        pipeline.detect_circles()
        pipeline.draw_circles()

        large_circles = []
        small_circles = []

        for circle in pipeline.circles[1:]:
            pipeline.draw_distance(circle)

            # split circles in large and small
            if circle[2] > 35 and circle[2] < 50:
                large_circles.append(pipeline.calculate_h_v_distance((circle[0], circle[1])))
            elif circle[2] > 15 and circle[2] < 25:
                small_circles.append(pipeline.calculate_h_v_distance((circle[0], circle[1])))

        position_queue.put({"large": large_circles, "small": small_circles, "image": pipeline.image})

    pipeline.store_calibration()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()

def run_relay_controller(relay_controller, relay_control_queue, relay_status_queue):
    while True:
        if not relay_control_queue.empty():
            commands = relay_control_queue.get()
            for command in commands:
                if command[0] == "on":
                    relay_controller.on(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "off":
                    relay_controller.off(command[1])
            relay_status_queue.put(relay_controller.status)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    position_pipeline = PositionPipeline()
    relay_controller = RelayControl([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

    relay_control_queue = Queue()
    relay_status_queue = Queue()
    position_queue = Queue()
    frame_queue = Queue()


    position_process = Process(target=run_pipeline, args=(position_pipeline, position_queue))
    relay_process = Process(target=run_relay_controller, args=(relay_controller, relay_control_queue, relay_status_queue))
    server_process = Process(target=run_webserver, args=())
    position_process.start()
    relay_process.start()
    server_process.start()

    
    relay_status = None
    circles = None

    while True:
        try: 
            if not position_process.is_alive() or not relay_process.is_alive():
                print("Process died")
                print(f"Position process alive: {position_process.is_alive()}")
                print(f"Relay process alive: {relay_process.is_alive()}")
                break
            
            relay_control_queue.put([("on", 1), ("off", 2)])
            
            if not position_queue.empty(): circles = position_queue.get(block=False)
            if not relay_status_queue.empty(): relay_status = relay_status_queue.get(block=False)

            if circles is not None:
            # print(f"Circles large: {circles['large']}")
                #print(f"Circles small: {circles['small']}")
                frame_queue.put(circles["image"])
                # check if there are still circles in the image, and if not --> initialize refill
            
            if relay_status is not None:
                None
                #print(f"Relay status: {relay_status}")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Keyboard interrupt")
            position_process.terminate()
            position_process.join()
            print("Position process killed")
            relay_process.terminate()
            relay_process.join()
            print("Relay process killed")
            server_process.terminate()
            server_process.join()
            print("Server process killed")
            break

    print("Processes alive: ", position_process.is_alive(), relay_process.is_alive(), server_process.is_alive())
    sys.exit()
```

And this is the output:

```
Keyboard interrupt
Position process killed
Relay process killed
Server process killed
Processes alive:  False False False
```

But the main process never gets terminated.

Here is a Minimal Reproducable Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import sys
import time

def run_pipeline():
    while True:
        print("pipeline running")
        time.sleep(5)

def run_relay_controller():
    while True:
        print("relay running")
        time.sleep(5)

def run_webserver():
    while True:
        print("webserver running")
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    position_process = Process(target=run_pipeline, args=())
    relay_process = Process(target=run_relay_controller, args=())
    server_process = Process(target=run_webserver, args=())
    position_process.start()
    relay_process.start()
    server_process.start()

    frame_queue = Queue()

    while True:
        try:
            frame_queue.put("placeholder") # with this line the main process does not terminate
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            position_process.terminate()
            relay_process.terminate()
            server_process.terminate()
            break
    position_process.join()
    relay_process.join()
    server_process.join()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Because you ***catch*** the `KeyboardInterrupt`... You should `raise` instead of `break` in the `except` to let it make its effect

Comment: you are looping while True... it will never close except with an error/system exit

Comment: @Noah There is a `break` inside the `except` block...

Comment: Moritz - it will help if you could post a [mre] of your code. Right now we can't run and test a solution as you import some stuff and most of the logic seems irrelevant for the actual problem you're asking about. To help us answer you, and to make this question more useful for future readers - please dedicate some time to create a [mre]

Comment: @Tomeriko this is not really helpfull. I want to understand why this partucular case is not working.

Comment: What exactly is not helpful?

Comment: Your first comment. I tried to generate a mre. While doing that, I discovered the problematic line of code. It is the following:
`frame_queue.put("placeholder")`

Comment: The [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) implements an inner thread and needs to be [`close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.close)d as well...

Comment: Try `position_process.daemon = True`. May possibly attach it to the current process so that they'll shut down together.

Comment: @Peter I tried. But it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error stems from something with Queue maintaining a reference and not joining. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91185

A solution would be as follows :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
position_process = Process(target=run_pipeline, args=())
relay_process = Process(target=run_relay_controller, args=())
server_process = Process(target=run_webserver, args=())
position_process.start()
relay_process.start()
server_process.start()

frame_queue = Queue()

while True:
    try:
        frame_queue.put("placeholder") # with this line the main process does not terminate
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        position_process.terminate()
        relay_process.terminate()
        server_process.terminate()
        break

position_process.join()
relay_process.join()
server_process.join()
frame_queue.get() #Forcefully flush the queue
frame_queue.close() #Close the queue
sys.exit()
```

Although not ideal, I would recommend you utilize something like a kill command through the queue to terminate gracefully through a kill command etc. as recommended by the docs.

Comment: I tried to empty the queue and closing it. But with no effect.

Comment: For now I have a kind of fix, where I use the line: `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)` instead of `sys.exit()`. This is by no means a good solution. But for now it works!